# powershell list of unique parts of filename

Tags: sorting, powershell, unique, filenames

I have multiple machines uploading files to one FTP directory. The first part of the filename is the machine, the rest is a timestamp, e.g. AAAAA_20130312_125113.

Now I want to get a sorted list of all Unique machines that have uploaded to this directory.
I managed to write the lost of all filenames.substring(0,5) to the host but I still don't have the unique machine names.

```
$files=Get-ChildItem $strMOVETO -Name -Include TAS*.csv -Recurse
ForEach ($i in $files) { Write-Host $i.Substring(0,5) }
```

Any hints on how to do this? Does not necessary have to be a one liner, although that would be a nice challenge ;-).

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is generally the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, thereby bypassing PowerShell's success output stream and thus the ability to send the output to other commands, capture it in a variable or redirect it to a file. That said, in PSv5+ `Write-Host` now writes to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output _can_ be captured, but only via `6>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens when you have an 8-character machine name? Your `substring` will break. Since the machine name, date & time are delimited by an `_`, split on that & get the first item.

```
Get-ChildItem $strMOVETO -recurse -name -include TAS*.csv|%{$_.split("_")[0]}|sort-object -unique
```

To filter on date as well:

```
Get-ChildItem $strMOVETO -recurse -include TAS*.csv|where-object{$_.lastwritetime -ge (get-date).adddays(-1)}|%{$_.basename.split("_")[1]}|sort-object -unique
```

Comment: Machine name-length is indeed variable. Assuming [1] instead of [0] would take the second item (TAS_xxxxxxxx as in the Filter), put a } before the last pipe and it is complete! Thanks

Comment: Can I combine this command with a Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} ?!? If I leave out the -Name tag the Split does not work, if I use the -Name tag the LastWriteTime is not available ...

Comment: Yes you can - see my edit. The split isn't working because now that you've omitted `-Name`, you're getting a collection of objects back, not just a list of names.

Comment: Briliant, you saved my day ;-)

Comment: Note that `-Name` when combined with `-Recurse` returns (relative) _paths_ rather than mere file _names_ for files located further down the subtree, in which case `$_.split("_")[0]` won't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $strMOVETO -Name -Include TAS*.csv -Recurse | % { $_.Name.Substring(0,5) } | Sort -Unique
```

You don't need to do the Write-Host inside the loop and it's easier to use % instead of a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

pipe the results of your command into a `| sort -unique`

```
$files=Get-ChildItem $strMOVETO -Name -Include TAS*.csv -Recurse
ForEach ($i in $files) { Write-Host $i.Substring(0,5) } | sort -unique
```

...but better still would be to simplify the script...

```
$filter = "TAS*.csv"
Get-ChildItem -Path $strMOVETO -Filter $filter -Recurse | % {$_.BaseName.Substring(0,5) } | sort -unique
```