# Finding unique filename parts in path

Tags: shell, powershell, parsing

I have a folder with a bunch of files in the format `xxxxxx_MMddyyHHmmss.json`. I want to find the unique `xxxxxx` components because some are duplicates just created at different times.

I referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360525/powershell-list-of-unique-parts-of-filename) question, but as someone who rarely ventures into Powershell, I can't get it working.

```bsh
$result = Get-ChildItem  C:\Users\<me>\Desktop\FileData\* -recurse -name -include *.json|%{$_.split("_")[0]|sort-object -unique
```

But I can't get it to actually execute. It just goes to the next line when hitting return.

Ideally, I could pipe it to a file to review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your command (the `%` (`ForEach-Object`) call's script block (`{ ... }`) is missing a closing `}`), but it should work in principle.

A streamlined, faster, and more readable version is this:

```
Get-ChildItem $HOME\Desktop\FileData -Recurse -Filter *.json | 
  ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -split '_')[0] } |  
    Sort-Object -Unique
```

- `Get-ChildItem $HOME\Desktop\FileData -Recurse -Filter *.json` returns file-info objects for all `*.json` files in the directory subtree of `$HOME\Desktop\FileData`
- `ForEach-Object { ($_.Name -split '_')[0] }` transforms each file-info input object into the first `_`-separated token of its name.

  - Note that I've switched from using the .NET `[string]` type's `.Split()` *method* (`$_.Split("_")[0]`) to using PowerShell's `-split` *operator* (`($_ -split "_")[0]`), because [`-split` is generally preferable for its flexibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41905031/45375).
  - That said, when performance matters, `.Split()` is noticeably *faster*.
- `Sort-Object -Unique` then sorts the resulting tokens and returns only unique ones (omits duplicates).
- Using `-Filter *.json` instead of `-Include *.json` speeds up the file retrieval, because the `-Filter` parameter is more efficient, due to filtering at the source.

---

#### Superior alternative solution:

[TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician) suggests use of [`Group-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) which allows you to retain information about the individual input files that share a given prefix:

```
Get-ChildItem $HOME\Desktop\FileData -Recurse -Filter *.json |
  Group-Object { ($_.Name -split '_')[0] } |
    Sort-Object Name
```

<sup>Note: If you don't need the unique prefixes to be *sorted*, you can omit the `Sort-Object` call, in which case they will appear in the order in which they're encountered during file traversal.</sup>

This results in output objects that contain the unique prefixes in property `.Name`, as well as all the files that have that prefix in the `Group` property, which prints something like the following:

```
Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 abcdef                    {/tmp/abcdef_file1, /tmp/abcdef_file1}
...
```

To get *just* the unique prefixes, as in the first command, wrap the entire command in `(...).Name`.

TheMadTechnician also suggests a slightly faster - though potentially a little more obscure - alternative for extracting the prefix: `$_.Name -replace '_.*'` uses the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) to remove everything from the first `_` in a name.
However, `$_.Split("_")[0]` is still the fastest solution overall.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: I looked at performance a little more: while `-replace '_.*'` is faster than `($_.Name -split '_')[0]`, `$_.Split("_")[0]` seems to be the fastest by far.